# table staff and store have the foreign key of other,how to create the table without delete one foreign key

Tags: mysql, foreign-key-relationship

in the MySQL's Sample Salika (DVD Rental) Database, the table of the staff have a foreign key is the table of the store field, the foreign key of the store have a foreign key is the table of the store field, how to create table without delete one foreign key, I used MySQLWorkbench.

```
    CREATE TABLE staff (
  staff_id     TINYINT     UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  first_name   VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  last_name    VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  address_id   SMALLINT    UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  picture      BLOB        DEFAULT NULL,           -- Kept a picture as BLOB (up to 64KB)
  email        VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  store_id     TINYINT     UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  active       BOOLEAN     NOT NULL DEFAULT TRUE,  -- BOOLEAN FALSE (0) TRUE (non-0)
  username     VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
  password     VARCHAR(40) BINARY DEFAULT NULL,    -- BINARY??
  last_update  TIMESTAMP   NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY  (staff_id),
  KEY idx_fk_store_id (store_id),
  KEY idx_fk_address_id (address_id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_staff_store FOREIGN KEY (store_id) REFERENCES store (store_id)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT fk_staff_address FOREIGN KEY (address_id) REFERENCES address (address_id)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE store (
  store_id          TINYINT    UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  manager_staff_id  TINYINT    UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  address_id        SMALLINT   UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  last_update       TIMESTAMP  NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (store_id),
  UNIQUE KEY idx_unique_manager (manager_staff_id),  -- one manager manages only one store
  KEY idx_fk_address_id (address_id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_store_staff FOREIGN KEY (manager_staff_id) REFERENCES staff (staff_id) 
    ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT fk_store_address FOREIGN KEY (address_id) REFERENCES address (address_id) 
    ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: I forgot set the  : FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;

Comment: If you happened to answer your own question please feel free to add your answer and mark it as accepted.

Comment: @AJT_82: please do not add [solved] to titles here, or add solutions to the question. Add an answer instead, making it Community Wiki if you would rather not take credit for it.

Comment: @halfer. If you checked the comment above by OP. The solution was provided by OP. Well, so I won't take credit for myself :D :D That's why I added it. Seen just many people do this (add solved and the answert) But good to know if I'm not supposed to. No one has mentioned that before, but thanks for the info, and sorry for confusion!

Comment: @AJT_82: yep, I was aware it was not yours. The "community wiki" answer option would be useful here. Yes, lots of people do it here, and unfortunately it creates a lot of work for editors to unpick.

Comment: Yes, understood! :)